# 2322: is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint

Tags: typescript

Would someone know why `addChildrenDefaultValue` works but `addChildrenDefaultValue2` throws

```
Type '(Omit<T, "children"> & { children: ObjectWithChildren<TestObject>[]; })[]' is not assignable to type 'ObjectWithChildren<T>[]'.
  Type 'Omit<T, "children"> & { children: ObjectWithChildren<TestObject>[]; }' is not assignable to type 'ObjectWithChildren<T>'.
    Type 'Omit<T, "children"> & { children: ObjectWithChildren<TestObject>[]; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      'Omit<T, "children"> & { children: ObjectWithChildren<TestObject>[]; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'TestObject'.(2322)
```

? Is there a better way to do this? (I'm using extends cause in my use case it extends more types)

---

```
interface TestObject{
  name: string;
  children?: TestObject[] | null;
}

type ObjectWithChildren<T> = T & {children: ObjectWithChildren<T>[]};

function addChildrenDefaultValue(
  taxonomy: TestObject[]
): ObjectWithChildren<TestObject>[] {
  return taxonomy.map(({children, ...props}) => {
    return {...props, children: addChildrenDefaultValue(children ?? [])};
  });
}

function addChildrenDefaultValue2<T extends TestObject>(
  taxonomy: T[]
): ObjectWithChildren<T>[] {
  return taxonomy.map(({children, ...props}) => {
    return {...props, children: addChildrenDefaultValue2(children ?? [])};
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it throws an error is two fold.

1. Because your interface references itself, the type T has children of type TestObject[] and not T[] like you were likely wanting. This makes the types potentially incompatible (T could be many things, but TestObject cannot).
2. The use of map in that way (with a spread, and then the property redefined) is omitting children, and then re-adding it with a non-optional definition. So the type of the recursive type needs to reflect that.

```
type TestObject<TChild> = {
  name: string;
  children?: TChild[] | null;
}

type ObjectWithChildren<T extends TestObject<T>> = Omit<T, "children"> & 
{children: ObjectWithChildren<T>[]};

function addChildrenDefaultValue2<T extends TestObject<T>>(
  taxonomy: T[]
): ObjectWithChildren<T>[] {
  return taxonomy.map(({children, ...props}) => {
    return {...props, children: addChildrenDefaultValue2<T>(children ?? [])};
  });
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I was heading in the same direction too. I was just missing the `Omit<T, "children">`

Comment: Didn't know this - [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUB2BDAthAXFAM7ABOAlhgOYoC+KKokUAQgrFAGTJqa4GYArjgBGEUnQYB6KVEpyMwcUQgBjYOQD2GOQDMowABbRgAd00HwEIlENYAbtCzF+UMKU2RSoFDIPHLZk19I2h3T3FQKFNyABtYqDEFJVIVdS0dYP8IX1lwryimaygAEwhdSggShUTNI2zA6wA6XKgACXFoEgpqLiFRcXYMCEcJVW0SKE0RACtCNkRUdGw8QgBGKD9xD1JCFehyG2HRuiA). Thanks @Tim. Please add this explanation to your answer too. I will bookmark :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following type

```js
type TestObjectExtended = TestObject & {
    age: number
}
```

The type of `children` property in `TestObjectExtended` is `TestObject[] | null | undefined`. So, in the function `addChildrenDefaultValue2`, property `children` of `T` will have same type - `TestObject[] | null | undefined`.

Now in the callback/mapper of `map` function, `children` has type `TestObject[] | null | undefined` instead of `T[] | null | undefined`. In the recursive call of `addChildrenDefaultValue2`, children necessarily does not satisfy the constraint of the function as it is `TestObject[]` (if not `undefined`/`null`) but expected is `T[]`.

**QED**

Comment: Close, but there are actually two problems in play here. Try it out in the Typescript playground, and you will see that just fixing the children to be the generic type doesn't make the code work.

Comment: @Tim Yeh, actually, I figured out the problem only, I didn't provide any fix. I was working on the fix.